# read excel file, work around or with nil? values, edit/format individual column

Tags: ruby, format, spreadsheet, null

I have a spreadsheet with 146 columns and 530 rows. I want to iterate through certain columns, find nil values and change the value based on the class type. I cant figure out how to do this, right now I have this going for me:

```
require 'spreadsheet'


Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
raw_data = Spreadsheet.open '../October 2014.xls'
raw_data_sheet = raw_data.worksheet 0

designated_rows = raw_data_sheet.each {|row| [row[6], row[7], row[15], row[14], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[139], row[3], row[19]]}
```

I have tried iterations like `if row[3].nil? ? row[3] = "blank" : row[3].strip!; end` but I can only get these to run, not actually change the value of column 3 in this file. I would preferably like to find the nil values in these columns and change them to a designated value base on their class, the classes look as follows:

`[String, String, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Date, String, Float]` with cell reference its `["row[6]: String", "row[7]: String", "row[15]: Float", "row[14]: Float", "row[16]: Float", "row[17]: Float", "row[18]: Float", "row[139]: Date", "row[3]: String", "row[19]: Float"]` if thats important.

can anyone assist with this one? would you need more information? thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`designated_rows` is holding the entire spreadsheet in memory, now that you have that variable you need to save it down as a new spreadsheet file, or you can do this after you've modified everything:

```
raw_data = Spreadsheet.open '../October 2014.xls'
raw_data_sheet = raw_data.worksheet 0
keys = ["N/A", "N/A", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "N/A", "N/A", 0.0]
raw_data_sheet.each do |row|
  example_row.each_with_index { |val, i| example_row[i] = keys[i] if val.nil? }
end
raw_data.write '../October 2014.xls'
```

example for the `nil` logic:

```
[7] pry(main)> example_row = ["hi", nil, 9.9, 8.8, nil, 5.5, 1.2, nil, "hello", 1.1]
=> ["hi", nil, 9.9, 8.8, nil, 5.5, 1.2, nil, "hello", 1.1]
[8] pry(main)> example_row.each_with_index { |val, i| example_row[i] = keys[i] if val.nil? }
=> ["hi", "N/A", 9.9, 8.8, 0.0, 5.5, 1.2, "N/A", "hello", 1.1]
```

Comment: do you know the best logic to use to iterate through and change `nil` values?

Comment: "N/A" if column class = String or Date, 0.0 if column class = Float, thanks for the feedback by the way makes sense now how I can apply changes.

Comment: any suggestions for transforming the nil values? thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example row to fix and the column classes associated.

Comment: for instance, row[3] will occasionally contain nil values, typically these values are Strings like "Rep 100". I am looking for the best way to process these as: row[3].nil? if true change that cell to "N/A", else check next cell in column. thanks for any feedback you can provide.

Comment: Check out what I've done in my edit.  This uses a key's array, that basically holds the default values you care about should a row have any nil values.